# Creating manual anomaly detection in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, alerts

I realize that Cloudwatch comes with its own anomaly detection alarms, but I was hoping to build my own from scratch rather than relying on a black box algorithm.

I'm looking at time series that should be very stable (the proportion of null values that I read from various external tables), trying to see if there are upward spikes (unexpected increases in nulls)

To that end, I was thinking I would

1. log the proportion of nulls in each column once a day to cloudwatch
2. Programmatically create a metric based on all these proportion metrics that would look like

```
(null_pct - AVG(null_pct)) / STDDEV(null_pct)
```

(in Cloudwatch math), across 7-day rolling windows

3. Programmatically create alarms if any of the metrics from 2. ever increase beyond the static threshold of X (representing a spike of more than X standard deviations from the week's mean)

Does that make sense / sound doable? Or should I go about it some other way?

Comment: how are you going to do pt 1 and fetch the null pct at each timestamp/series?

Comment: @SathyajithBhat every day, I read the latest version of a table with `n` columns. I calculate the null pct for each column, and then log each value to Cloudwatch where `ts=today`, so I add one data point to each of the `n` time series I'm maintaining